# programmatically finding the size of float

Tags: java

Disclaimer: this question may not have practical value, it's more of a puzzle/curiosity question.

In Java I can write the following code to programmatically find the size of int:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int x = 1;
    int count = 1;

    while((x = x << 1) != 0)
    {           
        count++;
        System.out.println("x: " + x + ", " + count);
    }

    System.out.println("size: " + count);
}
```

Is there a similar way to programmatically find the size of Java's float?

Comment: If you want to find the size of a primitive data type in java, I suggest you to take a look here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html otherwise you can programmatically find the size by using getObjectSize.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

write the float into a ByteArrayOutputStream and get the length of the result.

```
import java.io.*;
class Test
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception
        {

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos =new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(baos);
        dos.writeFloat(0f);
        System.err.println(baos.toByteArray().length);
        }
    }

$ javac Test.java 
$ java Test 
4
```

Comment: I don't see the point of this. The answer will be 4 irrespective of value, and that much is written in the JLS. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding the question then.

Answer (score 2):

Java floats follow the IEEE floating point standard so you can easily inform yourself on the details. In a nutshell, there is no clean separation between the "used" and "unused" part of a float as it is with the two's complement integer encoding. The basic division is into sign bit, mantissa, and exponent. You may perhaps see what mantissa bits are used and what exponent bits are used, but it is far from a trivial task.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a binary search. Start at 0, then go for plus or minus 0.5*Float.MAX_VALUE and keep iterating.

This method would work for any number type - and should be much quicker than your loop above.

Comment: It's the storage size the guy's after.

Comment: @Marko That'll teach me to answer questions before having my coffee!

Comment: I managed to get the question wrong, too :) The real question is more trivial than it looked to me.